# configuring SW-precache webpac plugin: can it work with get in the URL?

Tags: laravel-5, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

Right now in our web app, we have a route that goes like this:

```
Route::get('/{storeName}','HomeController@mainPage');
```

And using the name of the Store, we load the information of the store, using different templates, depending on the specialty of the store. We have several views, selectin which one to load in the controller:

```
  class HomeController extends Controller
    {
       public function mainPage($storeName)
      {
       (..... Calls to the DB and other things........)
       return view('homePage/'.$store->template,[store-data])
      }
   }
```

We've been considering migrating to a Progressive Web App, and I've been looking into service worker precache. I'm wondering how can I do something similar in the dynamicUrlToDependencies.

So far, as I understand it, it works by passing the URL, and then the view, this:

```
module.exports.plugins.push(
    new SWPrecacheWebpackPlugin({
        cacheId: 'pwa',
        filename: 'service-worker.js',
        staticFileGlobs: ['public/**/*.{css,eot,svg,ttf,woff,woff2,js,html}'],
        minify: true,
        stripPrefix: 'public/',
        handleFetch: true,
        dynamicUrlToDependencies: {
            '/': ['resources/views/landing/landing.blade.php'],
            '/planes': ['resources/views/landing/new-precios.blade.php'],
            '/registro': ['resources/views/landing/registro.blade.php'],
            '/politicas-privacidad': ['resources/views/landing/politicas.blade.php'],
            '/articles': ['resources/views/articles.blade.php']
        },
        staticFileGlobsIgnorePatterns: [/\.map$/, /mix-manifest\.json$/, /manifest\.json$/, /service-worker\.js$/],
        runtimeCaching: [
            {
                urlPattern: /^https:\/\/fonts\.googleapis\.com\//,
                handler: 'cacheFirst'
            },
            {
                urlPattern: /^https:\/\/www\.thecocktaildb\.com\/images\/media\/drink\/(\w+)\.jpg/,
                handler: 'cacheFirst'
            }
        ],
        importScripts: ['./js/push_message.js']
    })
);
```

How can I put something like `/{$storeName}` in the dynamicToUrlDependencies? can I call a folder of views, like `['resources/views/homePagesTemplates/*.blade.php']`? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a direct method, but I hope this helps ..

**1- php artisan make:view**
you can get this [package](https://github.com/svenluijten/artisan-view) which can make views and scrape views.

Also, it includes extending other templates which what you are going to have ready for each kind of store.

**2- run artisan from your controller** you can do it in many ways, i'm just copy pasting Laravel code for [reference](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/artisan#programmatically-executing-commands)

```
Route::get('/foo', function () {
$exitCode = Artisan::call('email:send', [
    'user' => 1, '--queue' => 'default'
]);

//
});
```

so combining both together in your controller:

```
$store1View = \Artisan::call('make:view'['name' => 'store1Variation', '--extends' => 'stores.store1']);
```